# Can I set the firebase.functions 's config value in cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've a use case, where in I want to maintain some rarely changing constants in firebase and load them into my cloud functions project (project-1) when there is a `constants.changed` config value is set to `true`. During the next request execution, I'll update my JS file with modified constants and reload the node cache for that file using

`delete require.cache[require.resolve('./constants.js')]`.

Also, here I want to re-set the flag `constants.changed` to `false` so that next request won't really do the same thing!. In this way I can avoid hitting firebase continuously in each request for that rarely changing constants document.

I could set this config manually, but I've another system (cloud functions project [project-2]) which actually makes these changes to the constants. Hence I want the cloud function in project-2 to to set the firebase cloud functions config value `constants.changed` to `true`.

Am I running after a mirage? is this even possible to achieve. I've checked int the documentation, but seems the [Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.config.Config) interface is not exposing such a functionality!

Comment: I tried this solution, seems firebase doesn't even allow me to overwrite the file!! `Errors while writing to the Constants file:./constants.js { Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open './constants.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1347:33)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve what I said in the question!

Two basic premise is not considered in the above requirement narration.

1. Cloud functions config when changed, the cloud functions using that config need to be re-deployed to make the changes take effect.
2. Seems the cloud functions running on the server are in read only file system.

Both the above two limitations makes it impossible to achieve what I've asked for. But it would be a nice to have feature (hot deployments!)